# Load an own javascript file to every website

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, firefox

How can I load my own javascript file `http://domain.com/my.js` to every page i visit with the browser (Chrome or FF).

Comment: You can write a browser plugin that does for you what you want

Comment: Use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) a plugin which allows exactly that

Comment: Or you could write a simple [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)…

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome, you create your own local "[chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions)."

On Firefox, you use [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/).